# How to convert Image to Base64 in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to convert an `Image` object to Base64 and then send it to a server using HTTP request.

Note: `Image` ≠ `UIImage`

This is my code:

```
struct MyView: View { 
    @State var image:Image? = nil // I want to convert this Image to Base64 when a button is clicked

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // ...
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say: “Note: Image ≠ UIImage”. True, but a SwiftUI Image isn’t anything of use. If you want to do something with the data, you need a UIImage. Just say `UIImage(systemName: "paperplane.fill")!` and away you go.

Comment: But, I want to convert my variable 'image' to Base 64.

Comment: "and away you go". Unless you're using a platform that doesn't support UIImage, like macOS.

Answer (score -2):

```
 func convertImageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String {
    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)! as NSData
    let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    return strBase64
 }
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried it with this: self.convertImageToBase64(self.image) and I got this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Image?' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: `self.convertImageToBase64(UIImage(systemName: "paperplane.fill")!)`

Comment: You have to use UIImage instead of Image

Comment: So, How to convert Image to UIImage?

Comment: Image is not UIImage so this is not helpful

Answer (score -2):

```
   func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    return imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: 
    Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
   }
```

Comment: The question talks about `Image`, not `UIImage`.